# My app doesn't release location services

Tags: ios, mkmapview

One of my apps does not release location services even when it's killed by the user.

Symptoms: the location services icon appears on the phone at all times.

It has something to do with the "background app refresh" setting on the phone but as far as I know I do not use any background services.

I use location services in two places in the app (should I be deallocating?):

Place 1:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Place 2: I have an `MKMapView` in one view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've started the monitoring using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, you'll also need to stop it using `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.

I normally do this by listening for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` and then calling `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.